# world-writable file analysis linux question

Tags: linux, security

I am trying to secure a linux Ubuntu box and I am no expert. I am following guidance available on the [net](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-security.html).

Section 15.2 discusses world-writable files. The following command

```
find / -type f -perm -o+w -exec ls -l {} \;
```

returns a long list of files all located under /proc.

My question is: is this a good or a bad thing regarding security? Should I do something about these files?

Thanks!

Comment: `find / -type f -perm -o+w -ls` will produce mostly the same output but in a shorter way. I hope you appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is there's nothing you can do about it, so don't worry about it.

Files under /proc are generated automatically, and aren't "real" files.  They are pointers to various OS settings and resources.  You'll probably notice they all have a length of 0 as well.

You can safely ignore these.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, don't care about files in `/proc` and `/sys`.